# That vs Whose in these particular sentences

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-meaning, relative-clauses, clauses

> 1. How many people are there **that** the Joker is not the reason for them knowing who Joaquin Pheonix is.

1 sounds unnatural.

> 2. How many people are there **whose** reason for them knowing who Joaquin Pheonix is not the Joker.

2 seems natural.

Is 1 correct? If not, then why?

Comment: It's a hard question to answer because both of your example sentences are awkward. (I'd probably word as: _How many people know who Joaquin Pheonix is because of the Joker?_) You might want to rephrase your question about _that_ vs. _whose_ with a better pair of example sentences.

Comment: Noun at the start of relative clause sounds ungrammatical. Is it ungrammatical? I think it is "not because of the Joker"

Comment: @lollei123 - I think my sentence is grammatical; moreover, trying to cram the "not" in there makes it awkward. The question is merely tying the fame of the actor with the notoriety of the role – it's not like anyone asking that question will be looking for a numerical answer.

Comment: No you got that wrong. Your sentence is grammatical, i was saying that your question was the exact opposite of mine.

Comment: @J.R. *How many people know who Joaquin Pheonix is because of the Joker?* isn't the same as the question OP is trying to ask about. His intended question specifically ***excludes*** people who know who JP is ***because*** he played the Joker - it asks how many know who he is ***for other reasons***.

Comment: @Fumble - Exactly. But, because those are two mutually exclusive sets (you either are familiar with Mr. Phoenix because he played the Joker, or you know him from somewhere else), either question will divide the populace into the same two camps, and therefore essentially ask the same thing. My main point was this: If the OP really wants to know when to use _that_ and when to use _whose_, these examples won't really take us down that road. Instead, most answers are bound to focus primarily on how awkward this construction is in the first place.

Comment: @J.R. oic. But if - as seems likely - it's a *rhetorical* question (expected answer: *Hardly any!*), I don't think you get the same "effective assertion" by asking how many people *only* know him from the Joker (expected answer: *Practically everyone!*). Whatever - I wish one of our users more familiar with the relevant syntactic terminology and "rules" would post an answer here. I'm not really satisfied with my own, because I don't know whether there's a definable principle debarring the use of a ***that-*** clause as per OP's example #1 (a construction nns often come up with, imho).

Answer (score 1):

Both OP's versions are awkwardly expressed, and #2 is also syntactically invalid because there's a missing second instance of the word ***is*** as highlighted below...

> 2a: *How many people are there whose reason for [them] knowing who Joaquin Pheonix is **is** not the Joker?*

Also note that although the "reflexive" pronoun ***them*** above is syntactically valid, it's not *required*, and most native speakers wouldn't include it in such constructions.

---

I'm not sure whether the use of ***that*** in example #1 is actually "ungrammatical", but idiomatically it's not good. A better way of introducing the "restrictive" clause (identifying the type of people to be summed up as the "how many" total) would be...

> 1a: *How many people are there **for whom** the Joker is not the reason **[that] they know** who Joaquin Pheonix is?*

---

In practice though, the exact question being asked involves a fairly complex restriction, so in a casual conversational context, even many native speakers would struggle to find a concise way of expressing that restriction. It's a bit different for me here because I'm *writing* (so I have plenty of time to think of how to phrase things), but in a real-world spoken context I think I'd be more likely to ask something like...

> 3: *How many people know who Joaquin Pheonix is **apart from because of** the Joker?*

Comment: Can you place a noun after "that" as I did in the first example by placing "The Joker" at the first?

Comment: In *some* contexts there's no problem with having a noun after "that" in such "restrictive clauses". For example, *How many people are there **that John** owes money to?* is fine. That's why I said above that I'm not sure whether your version is actually "ungrammatical", because there's no clear-cut rule saying when the restrictive clause has simply become too complex to be accepted as idiomatic / natural (which I *think* is the reason your version doesn't work, whereas my ***John*** version is okay).